# Module Not Found Requests in Python - Pip says it is there

Tags: python, module

I am running a Python3 production test server (Not running a development environment, but only available to a few users - so production configuration, but for testing.) The server is Ubuntu running Nginx in an Azure environment.

On my development server (Windows 10) running Django
I installed Requests and everything runs fine. On my production server when I try to run the application, I get a an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'requests'
```

However, when I check to see if the module is installed using PIP it shows it installed:
...
PyYAML                 5.3.1
**requests               2.22.0**
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0
SecretStorage          2.3.1

...
If just ignore that and do a PIP install, it says the module is already installed.
It sounds like the module is in the wrong place, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: The usual reason for this kind of thing is that your `pip` and `python` commands aren't using the same version of python.  i.e. `pip` is installing packages for, say, python 3.9, but `python` is 3.10.

Comment: You can check the exact versions with `pip --version` and `python --version`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you check your virtual environment and Path Environment Variable? and you can use `python -m pip install requests` (or `python3 -m pip install requests` for *python3*)

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't have a 50 reputation and StackOverflow does not allow to add comment less than that.

Comment: Slaps forehead... forgot to startup the virtual environment. Everything installed and working. Thanks!